# TabBased app + modalview in app delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a tab-based app. The app launches with FirstViewCOntroller. I want to display modalview when same tab item First View is clicked.

I am trying to add code in app delegate in tab bar's didSelectViewController method, but I am getting error as unrecognized selector is sent to an instance. Also, warning is displayed as presentViewController method not found.

I am adding code in foll. way:

```
ModalViewController *modalView = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalViewController" bundle:nil];
    modalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentViewController:modalView animated:NO completion:NULL];

    [modalView release];
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`PresentViewController` is a method defines in `viewcontroller` class, so you will have to call it from the `Viewcontroller` class. Since you have written this code in app delegate where self is not a `viewcontroller`.

So I would suggest you to use `FirstViewcontroller` class to execute this code

Comment: but, first view doens't implement tab bar delegate methods. How can I do it?